# Variable variables as array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I've successfully followed what I believe to be the correct steps outlined in the php documentation to create a variables from other variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php, but get unstuck when a variable is an array.

I include many arrays at the start of my php file such as:

```
$maths5 = array(
array(
    'csv'=>'file.csv',
    'title'=>"Number and Place Value",
    )
);
```

Then dynamically refer to them with user variables like this

```
$var = $_GET['subject'] . $_GET['year'];
```

From what I've read, I don't understand why

```
echo $$var;
```

this returns "Array" as expected, but

```
echo $$var[0];
```

returns "maths5[0]", not "Array", and

```
echo $$var[0]['csv'];
```

returns "Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array". I aiming to return "file.csv". I don't know how to interpret this error message.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: What about `${$var}[0]['csv']`?

Comment: BTW, building a variable name like that from input paramers is a *serious* risk! One could put all kinds of names in there and read variables that you don't want to be read.

Comment: Read up on complex syntax - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex. There is similarity to what you want to do, and how to include a var in double quotes.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thank you. Would removing non-alphanumeric characters suffice? Or, to check whether the new variable is in a pre-defined array of acceptable new variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use another variable:

```
$maths5 = array(
array(
  'csv'=>'file.csv',
  'title'=>"Number and Place Value",
  )
);

$var = "maths5";
$var2 = $$var;

echo $var2[0]['csv'];
```